# IF statement executing else for true variable and true for false variable CAKEPHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

For true I'm receiving "Successfully UNENLISTED(1)!" and for false I'm receiving "Successfully ENLISTED(1)!".

dump($swap) will return true and still execute the IF else while if it returns false it still execute as true

Am i not understanding something specific to CakePHP?

```
//to grab database entry
public function swapSub($user_id_main, $user_id_from) {
        $result = $this->find()
                ->where(['Enlist.user_id_main'=>$user_id_main,'Enlist.user_id_for'=>$user_id_from])
                ->first();
                dump($result);
        if($result['active']){
            $result['active'] = 0;
            if($this->save($result)){
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            $result['active'] = 1;
            if($this->save($result)){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

//display true and false statement. //$swap == TRUE/does not work either
            $swap = $this->Enlist->swapSub($user_id_main, $user_id_from);
            dump($swap);
            if($swap){
                $this->Flash->success(__('Successfully ENLISTED(1)!'));
            } else {
                $this->Flash->success(__('Successfully UNENLISTED(1)!'));
            }
```

Comment: What variable type is `$swap`? Is it a boolean?

Comment: just return `$result['active'] = 1` at the end that would work as Boolean too.

Comment: My guess is that the `save`s might not be working? You're not handling the situation where they return `false` at all, so errors related to that might be slipping through unnoticed.

Comment: Greg's probably on to something - if save isn't working, sub swap will return `null` not a boolean. You could make this more type-safe in general by specifying a return type on swapSub (append `:bool` after `$user_id_from)` so it'll error out if it's retuning null. nulls are falsely in PHP.  Also if you're doing a redirect after saving, it may be dumping the value of $swap to nowhere, then showing the Flash result in a totally different request thread.

Comment: save always returns as true or false never null unless record originally doesn't exist. I've also tried with 1 and 0 instead of true or false to no avail. I used $result->getErrors() and it returns NO ERRORS. the database changes each time its just the if statement executes in reverse. swapSub() is in the Enlist model file while the if statement is located in the UserController.  :( @ahoffner

Comment: ------ @GregSchmidt

Comment: I would operate from the assumption that PHP is able to determine truthiness just fine, it's definitely not suddenly treating true as false and false as true. That's just not possible. I still think maybe you're looking at `$swap` at a different thread than the flash is displayed, could try switching dump out for `var_dump` which will display the type of the variable in addition to it's evaluated value, and sticking a die() after it to be sure you're inspecting it in the right thread time. And your function 100% could return null if  `save()` is false. Add else's, or use `saveOrFail()` instead